# measurability, countable subset

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading a proof of a theorem where the setting is as follows: $T$ is a countable (potentially infinite) totally bounded set. Let $W$ be a continuous linear random map. We are interested in the quantity $\sup_{\alpha\in T} |\|W(\alpha)\|^2-1|$.

The argument which is presented in the proof is as follows: We have to check whether the supremum is measurable or not. Luckily, measurability is guaranteed since $W$ is continuous on the totally bounded set $T$. Hence there exists an at most countable subset $T'\subset T$, such that $\sup_{\alpha\in T}|\|W(\alpha)^2\|-1|=\sup_{\alpha\in T'}|\|W(\alpha)^2\|-1|$.

Can anyone explain how measurability of supremum guarantees that the supremum is attained at some smaller countable subset $T'$?

Answer (score 0):

I can explain why the supremum is attained at a countable subset, but not by directly using measurability of $\sup$.

If the supremum is $x$, take any sequence $\epsilon_n\rightarrow 0$ and consider the set $X_n$of $\alpha \in T$ such that $|||W(\alpha)^2||-1| > x-\epsilon_n$.

Select an $\alpha_n$ from each $X_n$ (which is guaranteed to be non-empty). The supremum of this countable set o $\alpha_n$ cannot be less than any value $x-\epsilon_n$ and must equal the supremum of the whole set.